# Count number of zero nibbles in an unsigned 64 bit integer

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

For example `0x1230560181feab00` has 4 zero nibbles and `0x00000123456780ab` has 6. How can I compute this quickly without doing an naive loop and counting? Any cool bithacks for this?

Comment: No, if we look at the number of 0 bits in the first example we have many more, `0x1230560181feab00 = 0b1001000110000010101100000000110000001111111101010101100000000` which has 38 zero bits.

Comment: He's talking about **nibble** - half of byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, first "gather the zeroness" of the whole nibble (the OR of all 4 bits):

```
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
```

Remove the junk:

```
x &= 0x1111111111111111UL;
```

Then just `popcnt` that any way you want, if you have the instruction available that's great. Of course that gives the number of nibbles that *isn't* zero, but that's the same information, just subtract it from 16.

If you're going to use a fallback, some of them can be optimized because you know that every nibble is either 0 or 1, so for example in the typical approach that starts with `ulong result = value - ((value >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555UL);`, you can skip two phases of reduction.

So you can use this:

```
x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0FUL;
count = (x * 0x101010101010101UL) >> 56
```

to do the final count.

Unfortunately trying to use that the nibbles are small there and therefore trying to remove the second to last reduction step by using a different multiplier only *just* doesn't work out - the final sum can be 16 but using `(x * 0x1111111111111111UL) >> 60` cannot result in 16.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know any resources that I could study and practice so that I can come up with these things on my own?

Comment: @James sure, you could read The Art of Computer Programming volume 4A chapter "bitwise tricks and techniques" (preprint available online)

Answer (score 1):

You might get some speedup by using a precomputed lookup-table of 256 or 65536 entries (1 byte or 1 short), telling you how many nibbles are zero. This costs you 256 or 64k bytes. A larger LUT would be unreasonable I guess.

A sheer speedup can be achieved if you allow SSE instructions, thanks to the magical _mm_movemask_epi8 operation, which packs the 16 MSb of 16 bytes to 16 bits.

You will need to mask out every other nibble, then compare the bytes to zero (_mm_cmpeq_epi8), then pack the bytes to bits, and use a precomputed LUT of 65536 entries telling how many zero bits there are.